# How to switch Fast Secure Contact form module of Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, module

I took over someone website as a administrator and i have to switch the language of the website from english to chinese. But when it comes to editing a certain post. I rant into this

[si-contact-form form='1']

So I would like to know what can I do to switch the language ?I read about mo file but i don t quite understand though.

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: Always check out the plugin's wordpress page first. http://www.fastsecurecontactform.com/how-to-translate

Answer (score 0):

> **Edit:**  The plugin in question *has* translation options. See http://www.fastsecurecontactform.com/how-to-translate

If it's a plugin, it's possible it has no chinese localization at all.

The best thing might be asking the author (or looking on the plugin page) whether there is support for multiple languages. If there isn't, you would have to add it - either by translating each term word by word (if you are planning to drop the english version altogether, and are fine with hard-coding chinese words into the plugin), or, if you want to be able to switch languages, you'll have to add real localization features to the plugin - [here](http://weblogtoolscollection.com/archives/2007/08/27/localizing-a-wordpress-plugin-using-poedit/) is an article on how to do that.